# What is Purpose of pIntermediate in UpdateSubresources?

Tags: directx, directx11

DX11 used [ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476486(v=vs.85).aspx) but now DX12 seems to use a new method [UpdateSubresources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899214(v=vs.85).aspx).  I think I can figure out *most* of the differences between these two functions but the *pIntermediate* parameter of the *new* function has me particularly confused.

Can someone help me understand what this new pIntermediate parameter is for?

I noticed the VS2015 Template I'm trying to work from sets up a local variable named vertexBufferUpload in a CreateDeviceDependentResources method which later uses it in an UpdateSubresources call; unfortunately, by the time I want to call the new UpdateSubresources method, the vertexBufferUpload variable is long out of scope.